# svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

Tags: svn, centos, lampp

I tried to set up svn in the LAMPP environment. My svn repositories are in `/var/svn/repos`, and the `repos` directory is owned by `root:root`.

Now, when running the command

```
svn import test http://localhost/svn -m 'init'
```

I see this error message:

```
svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
```

How can I make the command run successfully?

Answer (score 2):

You need the repository to be accessible by the web server (Apache). Change the user:group to something like apache:apache, httpd:httpd, or www-data:www-data.

Comment: I'm using lamp apache with root permission and I don't have apache user and group on my lampp apache

Comment: Your Apache server is running as root? That isn't common. Did you configure it that way yourself?

Comment: when I browse http://localhost/svn then showing this error This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
      <D:error><C:error/><m:human-readable errcode="200029">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable></D:error>

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with your error. Other than making sure you have your `/svn` path properly configured in a `<Location>` block with `DAV svn` and a correct `SVNParentPath` I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

please run this command under your repo after running "chown -R apache:apache *".
You have to change file and directory permission as well

```
 find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
 find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Comment: This worked for me on centos 8.2 CWP, SVN 1.10. I could only get it to work otherwise if I did 777 on whole repo. Looks like newer versions work better.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *SVNParentPath* Directory Here my directory path is `/var/www/svn`

```
cd /var/www/svn/
```

Create a Repository Under **SVNParentPath**

```
svnadmin create repo_name
```

Give Apache Permission

```
chown -R apache:apache repo_name/
```

Create a SVN User

```
htpasswd -m /etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd username
```

Assign Permission

```
vi /etc/svnusers
[repo_name:/]

username=rw
```

Restart Apache Service

```
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my subversion (1.6) on default repository of cent OS. 
Finally i un-installed svn and install latest version(1.8). My problem solved.

To install svn latest version follow this link.
http://tecadmin.net/install-subversion-1-8-on-centos-rhel/

Answer (score -1):

You might have run into the SVN issue with custom error documents. Fix it:

> If you've got a custom 404 ErrorDocument that's enabled under the
>   repository location, you might be faced with '500 Cannot load the
>   requested SVN filesystem' – solve this by resetting the ErrorDocument
>   directive in the `Location` block; a working configuration is below:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   ServerName localhost
>   DocumentRoot /var/www
>   <Location /svn>
>     DAV svn
>     SVNPath /var/svn/repos
>     ErrorDocument 404 default
>   </Location>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

This is from [RimuHosting's subversion HowTo](http://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/applications/subversion). The important line is `ErrorDocument 404 default` – add this to the `<Location …>` block that configures a location for SVN, reload the Apache config, and it should be fine.

<sup>(I guessed your SVN repo is probably mapped to `http://localhost/svn/` and adapted config directives in the quotation accordingly.)</sup>